# Need to move files locally using rsync in bash script

Tags: bash, rsync

can you please help me on below files having spaces in name are not copying need some help.

```
rsync \
  -avhs \
  --protect-args \
  --remove-source-files \
  --info=progress2 \
  `find $sourcepath -daystart -mtime 2 -type f` \
  $bavkuppath
```

Comment: In general, using `find` this way is not good practice. Think about NUL-separating its output and capturing it to an array instead.

Comment: ...see [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Comment: make sure to read Charles Duffy's link [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), especially the part about `-print0` and `xargs -0` which is generally a great fit for handling files with whitespace in the name

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want all the filenames substituted into your command line exactly the same way that command substitution would do it --

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ this MUST be run with bash, not sh

# obvs, fill these in with your real locations
sourcepath=/some/where
bavkuppath=/else/where

readarray -d '' sourcepaths < <(
  find "$sourcepath" -daystart -mtime 2 -type f -print0
)
rsync \
  -avhs \
  --protect-args \
  --remove-source-files \
  --info=progress2 \
  "${sourcepaths[@]}" \
  "$bavkuppath"
```

It may be better, however, to tell rsync to read the list of paths to copy *from a file*, and have that file be a process expansion written by `find`. In this case, your command would look like:

```
rsync \
  -avhs \
  --protect-args \
  --remove-source-files \
  --info=progress2 \
  --from0 \
  --files-from <(find "$sourcepath" -daystart -mtime 2 -type f -print0) \
  "$bavkuppath"
```

Comment: This is not working just want to know which option should i use for files having space in name eg. test 1.txt

Comment: Both options should be fine for files with spaces in the name. I'd need to know what you mean by "not working" to describe how to fix it; if it's a shell syntax error, for example, that means you're using sh instead of bash.

Comment: (or a version of bash too old to have `readarray -d` in the first example; that feature was added somewhere in the 4.x series, so it's unavailable with the stock bash 3.x in MacOS f/e)